# Mock Elasticsearch Aggregation

Tags: unit-testing, elasticsearch

I have a problem that should be relatively straight-forward but I find myself going into a deep rabbit hole

I would like to Unit Test my call to Elasticsearch - with the search request including the **aggs**. What is a good way to go about mocking the response?

Elasticsearch `RestHighLevelClient` is very complex ... one has to deal with the complex web of XContentType/XContentType parser call chains

Is there a simple way to mock the call? I have sample JSON responses that one would receive if we called ES from Kibana Devtools

```
private fun searchResponseFromContent(content: String): SearchResponse {
    val xContentType = XContentType.JSON
    val parser = xContentType.xContent().createParser(
            NamedXContentRegistry.EMPTY, // this would not handle aggrgations
            null,
            content
    )
    return SearchResponse.fromXContent(parser)
}
```

Generally speaking do people just not test Elasticsearch calls in their unit test? There doesn't seem to be any good solutions to mock calls to ES

Answer (score 0):

The answer is just simplify what `RestHighLevelClient` is doing internally:

```
private fun searchResponseFromContent(content: String): SearchResponse {
    val xContentType = XContentType.JSON
    val parser = xContentType.xContent().createParser(
            NamedXContentRegistry(namedXContentRegistry()),
            null,
            content
    )
    return SearchResponse.fromXContent(parser)
}

private fun namedXContentRegistry(): List<NamedXContentRegistry.Entry> {
    // add as needed from RestHighLevelClient:1748 on version 7.3.2
    // static List<NamedXContentRegistry.Entry> getDefaultNamedXContents()
    return listOf(
            NamedXContentRegistry.Entry(Aggregation::class.java, ParseField(HistogramAggregationBuilder.NAME), ContextParser { p, c ->
                ParsedHistogram.fromXContent(p, c as String)
            })
    )
}
```